# Using case and grouping function to substitute literal value for summary rows with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, case

I have a sql code here I've made and I am trying to figure out how to use the case and grouping function to substitute the literal values "*ALL*" for the summary rows with null values. I also want to filter results with states ending with AZ, MI, OH. Is this the correct way of writing the code?

```
  SELECT AccountDescription AS Account, VendorState, SUM(invoicelineitemamount) as LineItemSum
     CASE
         WHEN ISNULL THEN '*ALL*'
     END
 FROM ap.dbo.Vendors
 JOIN ap.dbo.Invoices
     ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
 JOIN ap.dbo.invoicelineitems
     ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
 JOIN ap.dbo.GLAccounts
     ON InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo = GLAccounts.AccountNo
 WHERE VendorState IN ('AZ', 'MI', 'OH')
 GROUP BY AccountDescription, VendorState WITH CUBE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GROUPING function returns 0 if the column value came from the data, and 1 if the column value is a NULL generated by the CUBE operation.

your select with case statement will look like this

```
 Select 
     CASE WHEN   (GROUPING(AccountDescription) = 1) THEN 'ALL'
        ELSE AccountDescription
   END AS Account
   CASE WHEN (GROUPING(VendorState) = 1) THEN 'ALL'
        ELSE VendorState
   END AS VendorState,
   SUM(invoicelineitemamount) as   LineItemSum
```

Comment: what does setting the grouping equal to 1 do? I just copied it from the book, it doesnt provide an explanation for why it does that.

Comment: @Lisa Tse, grouping function returns 1 for null values returned by cube for summary rows

Comment: @RADAR SQL Server 2012 most certainly supports CUBE, it hasn't been removed yet (not in 2014 either). ROLLUP is not functionally equivalent - CUBE generates summary rows for all combinations, ROLLUP doesn't.

Comment: @jpw, thanks , I got mixed up , I remember they removed some thing in 2012, not cube .

Comment: @RADAR, is there a difference if we set the grouping equal to 2?

Comment: @Lisa Tse, it returns 0 or 1, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx

Comment: @Lisa Tse, you can accept the answer if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

First, the `WITH CUBE`syntax is being removed in a future version of SQL Server and should not be used; `GROUP BY CUBE()`should do the same (or maybe you want `ROLLUP`).

Second, the change the`NULL`values to`ALL`you can either use the `grouping()`function, or `isnull()`.

Third, if your`VendorState`is just two letters then this:

```
WHERE VendorState IN ('AZ','MI', 'OH')
```

is what you want, but if it's a longer string (like`Portland, OR`) with the state code at the end, do like the sample code below:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(AccountDescription) = 1 THEN 'ALL' ELSE AccountDescription END AS Account,
    ISNULL(AccountDescription, 'ALL') AS Account, 
    ISNULL(VendorState, 'ALL') AS VendorState, 
    SUM(invoicelineitemamount) as LineItemSum
FROM ap.dbo.Vendors
JOIN ap.dbo.Invoices
    ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
JOIN ap.dbo.invoicelineitems
    ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
JOIN ap.dbo.GLAccounts
    ON InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo = GLAccounts.AccountNo
--WHERE VendorState IN ('AZ','MI', 'OH')
WHERE 
    VendorState LIKE '%AZ' OR 
    VendorState LIKE '%MI' OR
    VendorState LIKE '%OH' 
GROUP BY CUBE(AccountDescription, VendorState)
```

See the [reference documentation for GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) for further information.

On a side note, you might want to get familiar with table aliases which you can use to not have to repeat long table identifiers for example:

```
FROM ap.dbo.Vendors v
JOIN ap.dbo.Invoices i ON v.VendorID = i.VendorID
```

Comment: thanks so much so to clarifying. it looks like adding the isnull clause did replace the null vaules to 'ALL'